# Factorization of Proper Scoring Rules

Tags: inference, scoring-rules

Suppose that we have a joint probability distribution $P(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$. Given a sample $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, the proper scoring rule log score can be computed as follows:

$$S(P,x) = \log P(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$$

If the components are independent then the density can be factored as

$$P(X_1,X_2,...,X_n) = P(X_1)P(X_2)...P(X_n)$$

hence the score is:

$$S(P,x) = \log P(x_1)P(x_2)...P(x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log P(x_i)$$

In general it is possible to conduct inference with any proper scoring rule such that:

$$S_n(\theta) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n S(P_\theta,x_i)$$

given the sample is generated $IID$ by minimizing/maximizing the above expression.

My issue is that factorization of the joint distribution doesn't imply a summation of individual scores for other types of scoring rules.

So how come we can do inference using $S_n(\theta)$ with a proper score other than log score by summing up (or averaging) individual scores?

Comment: I am a bit unclear as to what you are asking about. We will usually sum scores, but not over dimensions, but over *observations*. And if each observation is multidimensional, then we simply have to evaluate the multidimensional score, before summing. I am not aware of any work on scoring rules that relies on decomposing additively over dimensions. Can you clarify?

Comment: @StephanKolassa $x_i$ are observations. It is the joint density function I am talking about. When it factorizes log works. Otherwise there is no good foundation to sum scores.

Comment: The last expression you show does not involve the joint distribution at all and so there is no factorization involved or required. It is meant to evaluate the modelled *marginal* distribution of each $x_i$, not their joint distribution. We average scores over observations because the definition of propriety talks about the expected score, which we approximate with a sample average.

Comment: @ChrisHaug could you please formalize mathematically what you are saying?

Answer (score 1):

We use (strictly) proper scoring rules to compare probabilistic predictions. The key requirement of propriety means that predicting the true data generating distribution will give the lowest score/loss on average. More precisely, $S : \mathcal{F} \times O \to \mathbb{R}$ is proper if
$$
\mathbb{E}_{Y\sim F} \, S(F, Y) \le \mathbb{E}_{Y\sim F} \, S(G, Y) 
$$
for all $F, G \in \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is some set of distributions.

Due to this property, we generally want to select forecasts which achieve lower expected scores. If we have some probabilistic forecast $F_i$ and some data $y_i$, $i=1, \ldots, n$ we want to estimate these expected scores, i.e. roughly speaking we use the sample average $ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} S(F_i, y_i) $ to estimate $\mathbb{E} S(F,Y)$.

The forecasts $F_i$ are not marginals of a joint probability distribution since most users of scoring rules do not aim to produce forecasts for this joint distribution, but only for the next time step. For instance, most weather services won't produce a joint forecast distribution $\tilde F (y_1, \ldots, y_{7})$ of the daily temperatures of a whole week. Instead, a one-dimensional forecast $F_i$ is produced each day.

If you want to exactly know why this estimation is done although the $F_i$ might not be all equal and the distribution of $Y$ might also change for each $i$, then you have to look deeper in the literature. [This paper](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/Gneiting2007jasa.pdf) is probably the standard starting point.